# Access key rotation for Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I came across this question below.

My question is that is it ok to regenerate key1 and update the connection string with key1 instead of key2 in the first two steps, like below:

[image]

Comment: thx! You want to post it as the answer?

Comment: Sure thing, see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not ok. As soon as key1 is rotated apps may experience connection issues until they are updated. By first rotating key2 and have all apps point to that key there won't be any service disruption when key1 is rotated.